# The stored procedure of MS Access database is not available

Tags: ms-access, ucanaccess

Calling MS Access's own stored procedure will throw an error, because MS Access comes with a stored procedure with only one `select` statement, and UCanAccess does not seem to support queries with only one `select` statement.

I use UCanAccess-4.0.4, thanks everyone.

[image: Procedure view]

[image: Query Error]

Answer (score 0):

> UCanAccess does not seem to support queries with only one SELECT statement

This is not a limitation of UCanAccess stored procedures *per se*. In fact, Access "stored procedures" can only ever contain one SELECT statement.

You have encountered a limitation in the UCanAccess implementation of the `Asc` function. `Asc` is really only intended to return the numeric ASCII value for a single character. So instead of

```
UCanAccess>SELECT Asc(category_id) FROM categories;
UCanAccess>UCAExc:::4.0.4 routine signature not found for: PUBLIC.ASC(SMALLINT)
```

you can use

```
UCanAccess>SELECT Asc(Left(CStr(category_id), 1)) FROM categories;

·----·
| C1 |
·----·
| 49 |
| 50 |
| 49 |
| 49 |
| 50 |
·----·
```